# Snippets aren't working when refreshing an edit

Tags: bug, edits, stack-snippets, syntax-highlighting

Yes the title isn't very clear but here is the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. You are in a question page where a post (either the question or an answer) contain a snippet
2. An edit is made to the post and you get the notification on the top to refresh the post
3. If you click you get the edited post and the button to run the snippet disappear. You are obliged to refresh the page which is annoying if you are writing an answer.

Here is a screenshot of a recent post after I refreshed the post:

> [image]

another one on a question

> [image]

There is no error in the console and I am running Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.100  (64 bits)) on windows 8.1. I have the same issue using last version of Firefox.

The same is also happening on meta. Use the below answer to test.

Apart from snippets, a similar problem is that code syntax highlighting doesn't work when refreshing an edit either, as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392257).

Comment: Oh damn it! I thought it was only an issue on my end. I've had some issues with various websites on my machine due to some combination of addons, settings, firewall, and network stuff. Wo when I saw this happening recently, I didn't actually verify if it was me or SO. Moreover, I *had* seen that happen before - I saw it for the first time few weeks back but it went away quickly.

Comment: The first few times this happened to me, I assumed the edit had turned the snippet back into an ordinary code block, but the edit history showed this wasn't the case.

Comment: [Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334625/)

Answer (score 7):

As posted [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340825):

> **The Problem**
>
> In [full.en.js](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/full.en.js), the function that adds syntax highlighting and snippet controls to posts (which is called `styleCode`, located on `window`) does not get called after an edit finishes. So, when the post is refreshed, the post body HTML gets replaced, but the snippet buttons are not re-created, and non-snippet code blocks do not receive syntax highlighting either.
>
> **The Solution**
>
> Stack Exchange can fix this by editing `realtime-se.js` so that the `postEdit` function calls `styleCode` after calling `reloadPosts`: Change
>
> ```
> reloadPosts([post.id]);
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> reloadPosts([post.id]).then(styleCode);
> ```
>
> (or do something else that eventually calls `styleCode`)
>
> In the meantime, if you find it annoying, us users can fix it with [this userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Style-Code-After-Edit-Refresh) that manually calls `styleCode` when a post is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

This a test answer to reproduce the issue. Keep this tab open, then ask someone else to edit this post. When the edit notification appears, click on it, and you'll see that the snippet buttons don't appear.

(Editing the answer *yourself* in a different tab / browser won't reproduce the issue, because Stack Exchange will not show the option to reload the post if you were the one that made the edit - see `if (payload.acctid == StackExchange.options.user.accountId) return;` in `full.en.js`)

Snippet example:

```css
body {
 background: red; /* <-- let's change the color */
}
```

Non-snippet syntax highlighting example:

```js
const foo = function() {
  console.log('bar');
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that edit, I was trying out a fix and it worked

Comment: @CertainPerformance I suppose a userscript is coming shortly? :)