# Is SO running another experiment by hiding the user information or is it a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-card

The user information (reputation + badges) are hidden for me. Is this a bug or another A/B testing?

> [image]

I can see only the editor information:

> [image]

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334878/332043)

Comment: was about to post the same

Comment: ok, so another experiment

Comment: my card look so bad now without my 100K :/ ... it's like I am a Ghost user with no health point ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hopefully just a bug.

Comment: I wish there were a way to opt out of these experiments.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's called user scripts.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I saw [the other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334880) after commenting :)

Comment: Saw this first hand now and...OK, fine, no rep. But [what bothered me is this](https://i.imgur.com/SBGslg1.png) - seems inconsistent. Also, it's annoying that you can't even hover, click, or hover the username to reveal it.

Comment: `.d-none {display: none !important;}` ...seems deliberate

Comment: @AndrewAllen this is common in CSS, most utility classes use !important .. Boostrap is made with a lot of them.

Comment: Glad I found this post.  Thought I was going crazy.  It would be very nice if these sorts of changes were publicised.

Comment: @AndrewAllen it's weird, since a user `!important` still overrides the site's. In fact, almost anything a user can do would override it like removing the class via a userscript. The *only* thing it stops is adding an inline style. So, I don't think it's actually to stop users, if that's what you imply.

Comment: Next experiment: We will hide questions tags to make all of them have equal chance to get answers.

Comment: We always say it's about the content, not the poster, soo I guess they're asking us to put our money where our mouths are?

Comment: This is a bug, a fix is incoming.

Comment: In the future there will be no rep. No avatars. No downvotes. Just questions with upvotes.

Comment: @Taryn - Wow, a **network-wide** bug? Yikes. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @j08691 can't tell which way's up but at least we're **welcoming and inclusive to everyone** /s

Comment: Rep is back again \o/

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I honestly don't care whether it's shown or not. It looks a bit odd just because I'm used to the old layout. However, I do want to be able to see the information, as it does help in providing a better answer. A slightly fictitious example, but a new user asking "how does this work" might be struggling with loops or if statements, if a veteran is asking, it's probably the design patter or more general algorithm they are asking. I'd prefer to tailor the answer to their needs.

Comment: @Floern not on the main site... **edit** now it's back on the main site. phew

Comment: @VLAZ false. There are for example 25K+ rep users who can't program their way out of a paper bag, but who know how to interact with a specific DBMS. They ask very poor questions. There are also users with 1000+ questions, 15K+ rep who still do not know how to use a web search engine.

Comment: @CodeCaster as I said *probably*. I have seen very high rep users posting off-topic questions about trivial matters. Still, I find those are outliers. I don't intend, nor want to explain basic syntax or language constructs to every person who asks a question.

Comment: @VLAZ I get your point, it's just that I usually infer the asker's experience from their writing and code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This was a bug which has been resolved. See [Dean's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334893/164200) for more details.

> No need for user scripts, this was an unintentional slip-up. We were
>   fixing some Google crawler errors for deleted user cards on
>   questions/answers and a set of brackets got missed in the code path
>   that renders schema.org attributes. That meant that this:
>
> ```
> RenderSchema ? @"<span class=""d-none"" itemprop=""name"">" +
> UserToShow?.ToString() ?? name + "</span>" : ""
> ```
>
> Ignored everything after the null coalesce operator (??) and the
>   missing  consumed the rep div. We changed it to:
>
> ```
> RenderSchema ? @"<span class=""d-none"" itemprop=""name"">" +
> (UserToShow?.ToString() ?? name.ToHtmlString()) + "</span>" : ""
> ```
>
> I'm afraid this was missed during review and I only tested the deleted
>   user case because I'm silly. Apologies for the inconvenience!
>
> Builds are rolling out now.

Comment: any idea if this one is also on the road: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388534/8620333 ?... it's a very annoying one ..

Answer (score 46):

If it's an experiment, let this serve as feedback:  **Please put back reputation and badge counts!**

Comment: I don't think you have enough reputation to make these kinds of demands! /s

Comment: @Kayaman actually, he has NO reputation.

Comment: @Braiam still better than a bad reputation I suppose.

Comment: @Braiam He does not have my reputation.  I just checked on it ;)

Comment: @Kayaman: Funny, sorta.   Apparently none of us do anymore, or maybe this is part of the misguided movement to devalue expertise.

Comment: @Braiam we will all have the same non-reputation now.

Comment: This is how communism starts

Comment: Is someone equating a score on S.O. with expertise? There are plenty of people who hit gold on a few popular questions who's S.O. score far outweighs any evidence they are experts.

Comment: It's an imperfect proxy but better than we had before.

Answer (score 8):

I think that there is a larger problem here when a bug is presumed by the community to be an intentional change to manipulate us. I hope the staff recognizes how this indicates a serious lack of trust and considers the consequences of not repairing that trust.

I assumed this was a bug because:

1. It was network-wide, and new stuff generally happens just to the trilogy first.
2. It wasn’t completely obscuring the reputation. It was still visible in certain views.

That people are jumping to the conclusion that secret tests are being run in preparation for a major change without the opportunity for community feedback is a problem. I believe that SE developers are trying to gather data to make good decisions instead of acting on assumptions. I think people don’t like change especially when they feel they have no say in what that change is or how it happens. I think there’s a communication problem when people freak out over a bug. That’s all I meant to say.

Comment: *when a bug is presumed by the community to be an intentional change to manipulate us* --> if the votes count wasn't introduced as a testing I would never think this could also be a testing but for sure a bug

Comment: @Machavity You don’t think that people jumping to the conclusion that  some secret test is being run on them is a problem? Maybe trust isn’t exactly the right word, but the over reaction is worrying.

Comment: Much better. Clears this up. Thanks

Comment: @Machavity and apparently the negative voting thing also had to be pulled for a few days because the implementation needed some more work. It seemed *completely logical* that this was another A/B test that might have been slightly broken.

Comment: I don't think it's because people don't like change.  I think it's because people no longer trust SE to do the right thing.  Good faith reciprocation requires exactly that; reciprocation.

Comment: @fbueckert That’s why my first instinct was to use the word trust. We should be excited that SE is running experiments to try to determine the right thing to do from data, but it seems that a lot of people are worried that they aren’t going to be asked for their input before things change. Our expectations haven’t been managed well.

Comment: It's not just expectations, Colleen; it's the overall mishandling of events the community feels strongly about.  Can we be excited that SE is running experiments?  Sure.  Can we trust them to act in ways the community will like?  Previous history says no.  It's not unreasonable for people to be upset and anxious at changes that are not communicated.

Comment: @fbueckert I fully expect that sometimes the company will have to do things the community doesn’t like. My problem is that the actions they take seem completely arbitrary and driven by how someone feels instead of by a well thought out process that ensures everyone gets heard and treated fairly. The community should be able to predict what sort of action will be taken in response to an event. The disportionate response and lack of due process over what Monica said when compared to things other moderators have said with no consequences has made everything very unstable from where I sit.

Answer (score 0):

If they're going to hide the reputation of the questioner and answerer, they should at least be consistent. It doesn't matter if you hide how much reputation you have on the question, I can still see it in the question "queue"/Search Page prior to opening it. This is pointless "feature" if it is one.

[image]

Oh, but I saw from the previous screen, User, you have 84 reputation!

[image]

Edit: it's a new feature, that isn't working as intended: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334893/397219

> this was an unintentional slip-up. We were fixing some Google crawler errors for deleted user cards on questions/answers and a set of brackets got missed in the code path that renders schema.org attributes.

Comment: This is probably a result of how A-B testing works, unless I'm misunderstanding. **edit** nevermind, I see that on the search page now.

Comment: A feature that hides reputation is a pointless feature... I feel like there's a good pun to be had there.