# Let us opt-out of UI experiments

Tags: feature-request, reputation, user-experience

There appears to be a UI experiment running, currently.

- [Vote counts are being "censored"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390269/is-so-running-another-experiment-by-hiding-the-user-information-or-is-it-a-bug) if a post scores below -1.

This experiment interferes with my normal use of Stack Overflow, and I want to opt out of it.

Especially the popup *every single time* I downvote something is annoying.

The fact that I'm aware of these experiments already removes the value my involvement, as I've taken to userscripts to reverse the effects:

- [Fix vote count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390255/1835379) (see the last paragraph in that answer)

Comment: FYI the rep and badges is a bug. There is a fix incoming.

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks, @Taryn.
I see I can also link to a comment here, so that's not a problem in this case.

Comment: I don't necessarily mind not seeing the negatives.  What I **do** mind is having to deal with the blue alert that popups up every time, informing me what is going on.  I learned what was going on after the first or second time.  Now it's just annoying.

Comment: @Taplar same with the notice that appears after you down-vote a question.

Comment: Adblocking it works... but i hate the idea of blocking all notifications.

Comment: Letting us opt out of UI experiments would screw up the results...

Comment: @opa: Being aware of the experiment wouldn't?

Comment: @Cerbrus In some cases *it might*.

Comment: The fact that I installed a userscript to get rid of the effects says it _will_.

Comment: There needs to be a better way to provide feedback and possibly allow for users to be removed after it started. In your case you added a userscript to alter the behavior of the UI that is being tested and having them know that and why you did it could be helpful.

Comment: Good point, Joe! The opt-out could be a valuable data point.

Comment: The notifications showing up time and time again are a UI bug in my opinion. Migration? Downvoting? What's next? "Do you really want to answer?". I'm a **trusted** user, remember? Stop f***ing babysitting me.

Comment: Have just opened a question on the [ethics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390343/ethical-considerations-of-the-ongoing-experiment-re-not-displaying-negative-scor) of the experiment - you may want to chime in...

Comment: @desertnaut: I'm not sure if I want to go the "ethics" route here. I made a slight edit to the question, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Cerbrus by all means!