# Syntax highlighting is missing after new edits are shown

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, live-refresh

For the last couple of weeks I have observed the following issue on Stack Overflow:

1. I open a new Chrome tab with a C# question to read it - the C# syntax highlighting is present.
2. Someone edits the question (changes text).
3. I click on the notification - the changes are displayed, but the syntax highlighting is gone.

If I refresh the page with <kbd>F5</kbd>, the syntax highlighting is back.

The posts should not lose its syntax highlighting after edits.

Comment: I guess it's the same root cause as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388534/snippets-arent-working-when-refreshing-an-edit

Comment: @Kaiido I think so. It seems like it's something to do with code formatting and reloading a post's content. Meanwhile it's been four months and nobody from SE has mentioned anything about it. It's *super* annoying, especially with the runnable snippets. I'd open a question, read it and try to click the example but meanwhile there was an edit, so clicking *on the post* would reload the post which means now the snippet is not runnable until I reload the page. And the same thing can happen *again* if there are multiple edits being done.

Comment: The root cause is exactly the same as in the other question, and the other question describes both problems (with syntax highlighting and with snippet controls), so I think this should be marked as a duplicate