# Why does syntax highlighting only work when previewing an edit to this old answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I made an edit to [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192062/150605) of mine.  Among other changes, I converted from indentation-defined code blocks to code fence-defined code blocks.  Despite the question being tagged as C#, I provided `c#` language hints for the code blocks because I like to be explicit like that; I have never had an issue doing that in the past.

Since the edit, I no longer see syntax highlighting on my answer:

[image: Viewing revision 5 of Stack Overflow answer 8192062: code blocks do not have syntax highlighting]

This is after giving the highlighting a few seconds to appear, Reloading the page, and Shift + Reloading the page.  I do still see syntax highlighting on the question and its other answers, however.

During the edit, syntax highlighting worked as expected in the answer preview.  You can see that is still the case if I start to edit from the current [Revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8192062/5):

[image: Editing from Revision 5 of Stack Overflow answer 8192062: code blocks have syntax highlighting]

I found [Snippets aren't working when refreshing an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388534/150605), but that relates to the prompt to reload a post while viewing it, whereas I have tried a full page reload as well as a "non-reload reload" by clicking the question title link at the top of the page.  I am also aware of the [change to a new Markdown renderer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/699943) (which only now do I notice is [scheduled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348750/699943) for...**today** on Stack Overflow), but I don't believe there to be any problematic Markdown used either before or after the edit.

I am using Mozilla Firefox 77.0.1 on Windows with uBlock Origin in [Medium mode](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Blocking-mode:-medium-mode) and the necessary whitelist rules for Stack Overflow to work properly.

---

Looking at the resulting HTML I see that my code blocks become `<pre>` elements with no CSS styles.  For example, the first code block becomes this:

```html
<pre>string path = string.Format("WinNT://{0},computer", Environment.MachineName);

using (DirectoryEntry computerEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path))
{
    IEnumerable&lt;string&gt; userNames = computerEntry.Children
        .Cast&lt;DirectoryEntry&gt;()
        .Where(childEntry =&gt; childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User")
        .Select(userEntry =&gt; userEntry.Name);

    foreach (string name in userNames)
        Console.WriteLine(name);
}       
</pre>
```

...whereas in the edit preview the same code block opens like this...

```html
<pre class="lang-cs prettyprint prettyprinted" style=""><code>
```

...and includes a whole lot of `<span>` tags.  So, that would seem to answer the question of why syntax highlighting isn't working (because there's none in the markup), but then raises a new question: why isn't the necessary markup for prettyprinting being generated?

Just as a sanity check, I found [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054587/150605) of mine with the same kind of formatting (code fence with a `c#` language hint despite the question being tagged as such, no empty lines surrounding the code fence) and the syntax highlighting works fine.

Comment: Just FYI: At lest in the past, the `<span>` elements within the `<pre><code>` are added by the in-page JavaScript that does the syntax formatting. It is the various CSS classes on the `<pre>` element which trigger the in-page JavaScript to perform the highlighting. The highlighting is not in the HTML delivered by SE.

Comment: I see you are using tabs in your code block, so it might be related to [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398552/i-cannot-edit-snippet-after-posting-an-answer), which is caused by tab characters.

Comment: @VLAZ I had considered that tabs might be the issue but found that the previous revision of my answer also used tabs.  Do you suppose the issue is with tabs and code fences or tabs and CommonMark?  Maybe the latter since the question you linked doesn't use code fences.

Comment: I really don't know. I actually tried your code in the sandbox and couldn't get any highlighting with tabs or with spaces. I mentioned the other one as a potentially related issue but I'm not entirely sure if it's actually related or not.

Comment: I reckon that's definitely a bug in the way that the c# tag after a code fence is supported. Changing it out for `lang-cs` makes it work as you expect. Not sure why the preview would show it fine, other than perhaps they differ in implementation. I made an answer there (now deleted) to have a quick test and changed one of the declarations to lang-cs; I now note that on the main page where my deleted answer shows pink the syntax highlighting is fine and on the edit mode it is now the preview that is broken.. ?!

Comment: Could it be [the passage to CommonMark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398481/stack-overflow-is-migrating-to-commonmark-on-saturday-june-20-2020) that breaks the `#`, maybe server-side. That would explain why it works in the edit mode, but not in the rendered post.

Comment: I'm noticing that answers using `\`\`\`c++` are not being syntax highlighted anymore, either. But previews work fine.  Answers are syntax highlighted if `\`\`\`` is used with a [tag:c++] tag, or `\`\`\`cpp` is used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good catch. This is something I messed up as part of [integrating the new CommonMark renderers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark).

A fix will go out later today that will make infostrings like ```` ```c# ```` or ```` ```c++ ```` work again. Thanks for spotting and reporting!

Comment: Thanks for fixing this! *sweats in fixing syntax highlighting on Unity questions*

Comment: I'm still not seeing syntax highlighting on the answer that inspired this question or [this newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643502/150605).  I even tried accessing it in a clean browser profile in case it's a matter of client-side components being cached.  I don't know anything about Stack Overflow's release process, so is this a fix I should being seeing live?

Comment: @BACON that's because the last edits were made before the fix was in. We only re-render questions and answers on creation or edit, so these two examples were still rendered with the bug in place. I've triggered a "rebake" manually, the two posts you mentioned now show correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks for your help on this, Ham.

Answer (score 3):

I was about to post about this when I saw you beat me to it.

It seems to be an issue with the Markdown content for codeblocks with the language set to `C#` specifically. If you change the codeblock's language to `csharp` the issue resolves itself and it will be displaying proper Markdown for C# in both the preview and the actual post.

Also this isn't just the case for edited questions either. Creating a new question and tagging codeblocks as C# will add the proper Markdown in the preview, but show none in the posted question.

I suspect that `C#` is an alias for the `csharp` Markdown content, and the aliasing isn't working properly or something. But I have no evidence to back it up. There is definitely a bug somewhere, though.

For now the simple fix is changing the `c#` in the codeblock to `csharp` (as can be seen in the edit history for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62515183/revisions)).

Comment: The canonical (the one with the most detail) wrt. code formatting is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)* (cross-site).

Comment: Interesting, if I read correctly Peter's link only `\`\`\`cs` would be valid, and indeed here on meta, that's the only one that works, with the front-end parser at least, didn't try the server-side one, which I believe is the one that has currently a problem with `c#`. However on main, any of these variants work in the front-end renderer, even on questions with no [c#] tag